# mypow() trough continued fraction and taylorseries return bigger number than pow()

Tags: c, pow, taylor-series

```
double taylor_log(double x, unsigned int n){
double tmp;
double sum = 0;
if(x < 1){
    int j = 2;
    x = 1 - x;
    tmp = x;
    sum = -x;
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i < n; i++){
        sum -= ((tmp *= x) / j);
        j++;
    }
    return sum;
}
else if (x >= 1){
    tmp = ((x-1)/x);
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        sum += (tmp/i);
        tmp *= ((x-1)/x);
    }
    return sum;
```

this is my fuction for log with taylor series wich work correctly.
Im using this formula to get exponetional fuction of number.[formula for mypow()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVb2T.png)
and this is my code for pow

```
double taylor_pow(double x, double y, unsigned int n){
double sum = 1.0;
int fac = 1;
double exp = y;
double lna = taylor_log( x, n);
for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    fac *= i;
    sum += (exp * lna / fac );
    exp *= y;
    lna *= taylor_log( x, n);
}
return sum;
```

}
Now my problem is that if i put for example 30 iterations for my function the number is higher than pow(). For example pow(2,3) = 8 and my result with 20 iterations is 8.0007... and its growing. Thans for all responses.

Comment: If it's growing: that sounds very much like an accumulating round-off problem: results of the intermediate calculations don't fit exactly into their temporary variable. You're simply running into machine precision limits, and I suspect the errors accumulate since you're mostly adding and multiplying (experiment: what's the result when e.g. `x=0.5` as input, where `tailor_log` gives you negative results?). If this is the case, you'll need find some smart ways (reformulations) to avoid those round-off errors.

Answer (score 0):

`int fac` is overflowing. Changed it to `long double`, and it works much better.

A 32 bit signed int will only hold values up to 12!, while an 80 or 128 bit long double can hold something like 2000!.

Comment: 128 bit floating number are very rare ! and long double is compiler behavior.

Comment: @Stargateur Yes, that's true, but 64 bits should be more than enough to get an acceptable value for 2^3, and 80 bits even more so.